# how to make sure a method is called first before others in java

Tags: java

I wrote a car program that has  four methods accelerate,brake,gear and start, and I want to make sure the start method is called first before any of the other three methods are called.pls how should I do this.

Comment: your program will have sequence, so clearly if you call it first or make some if statement to force it to be first everything will be fine

Comment: `boolean running = false;` Add that to your class. When start is called, change it to true. If other methods are called, only run them if `running == true`.

Answer (score 9):

This is called "keeping the current state". There are many ways of doing this, but perhaps the very basic one would be keeping a `boolean` variable that tells you if a car is started or not:

```
public class Car {
    private boolean isStarted = false;
    public void start() {
        ... // Do things
        isStarted = true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now your other methods need to check `isStarted` to see if the car is in a proper state:

```
void accelerate() {
    if (!isStarted) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Car must be started to accelerate");
    }
    // Do other things
}
void brake() {
    if (!isStarted) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Car must be started to brake");
    }
    // Do other things
}
// ...and so on
```

Answer (score 5):

> I wrote a car program that has four methods accelerate,brake,gear and start, and I want to make sure the start method is called first before any of the other three methods are called.pls how should I do this.

Maybe you should consider a different approach. For instance I suggest that you in fact allow all methods to be called, but don't have them respond unless start has been called. For instance, you could give your Car class a boolean variable, say called running, that is set to true by `start()`. Then your other methods do nothing if running is false.

So accelerate could look like:

```
public void accelerate() {
  if (!running) {
    // exit the method and return to caller or throw exception
    return; 
  }  else {
    // do what the method normally would do here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks think I can make something out of your tips

Comment: An alternative is `IllegalStateException`.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a simple flag to let other methods know you car is already started.

Something like:

```
boolean started;
start(){ started=true; }

accelerate() { 
    if(started){
       // Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could technically have a class `UnstartedCar` whose only method is a `StartedCar start()`, returning a StartedCar with `accelerate`.

Such a pattern would mean that the compiler would refuse to accept any files that don't operate the car correctly, and it would tell the user that they can't accelerate an unstarted car before they ever run the program:

```
UnstartedCar unstartedCar = Dealer.buyCar();
unstartedCar.accelerate();
```

would result in:

```
  error: cannot find symbol
    unstartedCar.accelerate();
                ^
  symbol:   method accelerate()
  location: variable car of type UnstartedCar
```

Meanwhile,

```
StartedCar startedCar = unstartedCar.start();
startedCar.accelerate();
```

would work fine, because the car was started first. This is similar to how some cars just refuse to let you shift out of park unless you're pressing down on the brake. It would permanently eliminate every single bug that could ever arise due to not starting the car before driving it (having the compiler catch it is known as "type safety").

However, while this is a really useful feature of an API which can prevent large classes of bugs and is highly sought after in other languages, it's **not idiomatic Java**.

Instead, the car is expected to explode if you try to accelerate without starting it (known as "fail fast", and illustrated in dasblinkenlight's answer). This sort of bug is very noticeable, easy to fix early, and more in line with common Java convention.

An older approach was to just not have the car do anything. This is no longer recommended, because bugs are harder to find. You only discover the bug weeks later when customers are complaining that their packages aren't delivered, and find all your drivers in the garage flooring the accelerator but not moving because they forgot to start the car first.